# Set the minlength property jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to set the minlength property of a input element using jQuery. Its required like that because it will vary.. Is there a jQuery api to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery validate plugins can do that for you

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/minlength

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
    }
  }
})
```